# Set Kendo DropDownList select box (not options) width automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I can set the width of the drop-down list (i.e. the list coming out of the select box) automatically with:

```
var localDropDown = $("#movies").data("kendoDropDownList");
localDropDown.list.width("auto");
```

But this is just the actual list. The select box (i.e. the box that contains what value is currently selected) will not be the same size. For instance, if I select an option with very long text, it will be cut off in the display when selected. I also don't want to set the width dynamically to always be the width of the current selected option, but rather the width of the largest option in the list. How can I set the box's width to be the same as the widest option?

Comment: If we load the Listitems for the drop-down on-demand then how we know the max width before loading it?

Comment: The Kendo docs say the width for the drop-down can be set on auto only after initialization like this, so I have no intention of setting width before loading; I wish to change the width after initializing these elements.